# Where is the tikz library named "quotes"?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I noticed it was mentioned a couple of times on this site, but I could not find any documentation for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is part of PGF 3.0, which was released on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) last December. It has not appeared on CTAN yet, and is therefore not in TeX Live and MikTeX, see http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/discussion/477362/thread/340b50b1/?limit=25#99f5